# Angular MatDialog not showing the gray background overlay

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using Angular 6. I've already included the theme. I am opening it like this:

```
   constructor(private dialogo: MatDialog) {



   }

  ngOnInit() {

   this.dialogo.open(CarregandoComponent);

  }
```

Here is picture of my dialog, clicking outside the dialog won't close it. Pressing esc will dismiss the dialog.

[image]

Comment: Check the console for errors!

Comment: No erros on console.

Comment: Make sure that you DON'T have the following in your module: `providers: [
    {provide: MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: {hasBackdrop: false}}
  ]`

Comment: @Faisal you helped me a lot! I set hasBackdrop: true and it worked. I don't think hasBackdrop is very descriptive name though.

Comment: Glad to help. You don't actually have to configure the `hasBackdrop` property in your module. By default, the backdrop is visible. We configure the property in module only for a global behavior. Btw, You can also set/remove backdrop from the dialog's `open(...)` method.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and solved it by importing the following angular material design in the global.scss:

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

The chosen material design ("indigo-pink") can be changed to your preferences. After doing so you can specify your background design in the config you pass while opening the dialog:

```
 this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, {
  backdropClass: "dialog-background",
  hasBackdrop: true
})
```

Your style can look like this:

```
.dialog-background {
  background-color: rgba(113, 113, 113, 0.44);
  backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
}
```

This will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution

You need to just include `@import '~@angular/cdk/overlay-prebuilt.css';`

or depend on how you are using CDK another solution here https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview