# Angular 10 Angular Material Dialog doesn't work correcly

Tags: angular-material

I'm trying to use angular material dialog. So I created a button to open the dialog.

**HTML**

```
<button mat-button class="btn" (click)="openModal()">Rate</button>
```

**TS**

```
import {MatDialog} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { DrinksModalComponent } from 'src/app/shared/components/drinks-modal/drinks-modal.component';

constructor(
    private dialog: MatDialog
  ) {}

openModal(){
    this.dialog.open(DrinksModalComponent);
  }
```

**HTML MODAL**

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Dialog with elements</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>This dialog showcases the title, close, content and actions elements.</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Close</button>
</div>
```

**Module**

```
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        MatToolbarModule,
        MatTabsModule,
        MatTableModule,
        MatSnackBarModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatDialogModule
      ],
 entryComponents:[DrinksModalComponent],
```

but when I click, it's open the dialog, but not in front of th e screen look:

**Expectation**
[image]

**Result**
[image]

Comment: Is this the first dialog you are using in this project and are you serving it with `ng serve`? Then maybe the MatDialogModule isn't correctly precompiled. Try restarting `ng serve`

Comment: I already tried that.

Comment: not sure if this still applies for angular 10 but you might give it a try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55432070/angular-matdialog-not-showing-the-gray-background-overlay

Comment: What component are you calling this method in? Is it declared in the module as well? By this i mean, you need a component to host the dialog.